# Error 500 using odbc in monotools?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, monodevelop

Hi I get an error running this code in mono tools?

Unsure how to fix?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Login1.Authenticate += Login1_Authenticate;
    }
    protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite; User=root; Password=commando; OPTION=3;");
        cn.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select * from login where username=? and password=?", cn);

        //Add parameters to get the username and password  

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", OdbcType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value = this.Login1.UserName;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", OdbcType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@password"].Value = this.Login1.Password;

        OdbcDataReader dr = default(OdbcDataReader);
        // Initialise a reader to read the rows from the login table.  
        // If row exists, the login is successful  

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            e.Authenticated = true;
            Response.Redirect("UserProfileWall.aspx");
            // Event Authenticate is true  
        }

    }
}
```

ystem.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented. Error 500[image]

Comment: What line is the exception being thrown on?  The error page should tell you.

Comment: please see attached image, this is the error thrown when I try to use the login page.

Comment: Alright, good. Start by looking at login.aspx.cs on line 37- what's there?

Comment: The main error is coming from the monotools OdbcDataReader.cs file on line 166, if you look at the first line of your stack trace in that image you can get the path.  It seems like the error is coming from the OdbcDataReader.HasRows() function.

Comment: Ive uploaded the the code that is in the cs file for that page, is this fixable?

Comment: So, is the line with `if (dr.HasRows)` line 37?

Comment: yeah! Thats the one, I have tested mono with a different odbc for a moment I thought OOO nooo mod-mono wont support odbc but it does and very fast!! Im running the site on nginx with mod_mono but its given me a headache trying to get things to work, and now this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HasRows is not implemented, but an easy workaround, I think, would be this:

```
if (dr.Read ()) {
...
}
```